# Storing hardcoded calldata in a Solidity contract

Tags: solidity, bytes, encoding

I've been trying to store a hardcoded call in a contract, but I'm getting confused on the encoding.

Let's say I have the following bytes:

0x9461d6f7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a796f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

This translates to calling `function testData(uint256 testVar, bytes32 otherVar)` with 10 & "yo".

If I store this as a bytes like so:

```
bytes public hardcodedCallData = "0x9461d6f7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a796f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
```

And then do a `address.call(hardcodedCallData)`, it does not work. The fallback function is triggered instead, assuming that it is malformed. When storing it as such, it seems it decodes to bytes that look different.

[image]

I seem to have a misunderstanding on encoding here somewhere. Given calldata, how do I store it as bytes as hardcoded, so I can do the above?

I tried variations (playing with strings for example), but not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that when you use a string literal like

```
bytes public hardcodedCallData = "0x9461d6f7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a796f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
```

Solidity interprets the string as ASCII. In fact, if you do

```py
"307839343631643666373030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030306137393666303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030"
.decode('hex').encode("ascii")
```

in Python, you'll see that this is the ASCII encoding of your intended hex value.

What you should be using is

```
bytes public hardcodedCallData = hex"9461d6f7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a796f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
```

See http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html?highlight=hex#hexadecimal-literals